# Unity3d rearrange a string

Tags: c#

Say you have a string 5/9/2010 and you want to rearrange it to read 2010/5/9. How would you go about doing that?

I want to sort a list by a string that happens to be a date. While I could make it into a date, I want to stick with a string, if possible because the time part of the datetime is hard to eliminate. (This is being used in an sqlite database for a Unity3d App.)
Forgive me if this is a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can guarantee that the string will always be the same input format, you can split the string on the `/`:

```
    string input = "5/9/2010";
    string[] inputSections = input.Split('/');
    string output = string.Format("{0}/{1}/{2}", inputSections[2], inputSections[0], inputSections[1]);
```

[Working Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/KISej3)

My code is very verbose, you can certainly simplify it for your needs.  I would also utilize the [string inerpolation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn961160.aspx) feature of C# 6 if it is available to you:

```
    string input = "5/9/2010";
    string[] inputSections = input.Split('/');
    string output = $"{inputSections[2]}/{inputSections[1]}/{inputSections[0]}";
```

Comment: Thanks! Looks like that's going to work beautifully!

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend parsing the date, in the off chances that the input date is not exactly in the format you were expecting, but was indeed a valid date. This is the situations parsing is for.

```
CultureInfo us = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US");
string input = "5/9/2010";
DateTime date = DateTime.Parse(input, us);

Console.WriteLine(date.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd", us));
```

You can test [here](http://rextester.com/NAREX12794)